# Web page does not work on android stock browser

Tags: javascript, android, wordpress, debugging, android-browser

I have developed a theme for wordpress and it works fine on all devices and browsers but Android native browser. The homepage is not adapting to the full size of the viewport and the javascript I wrote to make the slide is not working either. I can´t find the way to debug the web on Android Stock browser so I'm not able to figure out what is wrong. I have read that Android is not updating the browser since 2011 and I'm worried about if there is not a solution.

This is the URL of the web: [epsmotiongraphics.com](http://epsmotiongraphics.com)

I will apreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, try to avoid HTML5 things, because they are much likely incompatible with the stock android browser. Take a look at this site: http://caniuse.com/ . If that doesn't help, you can _try_ opening Internet Explorer, load your page, right click your page and select "Inspect". There will be an option to choose the IE version (Select one from ~2011), and according the version you select, he will adapt the site to that IE version. I know, those are distinct browsers, but it may help you to get the point what's wrong.

Comment: I just remembered, it doesn't have 'Inspect', but you can press F12.

Comment: Short: Open IE > load your page > press F12 > Click on tab "emulation" > Choose IE9 (Your scroll doesn't work in IE9, just confirmed, it might be a similar issue). Strangely, IE doesn't report any errors in the Console Log. Try adding more Log commands to your JS to identify the problem.

Comment: Also be careful with CSS3 animations, they might not work (correctly) in older browsers, such as yours (And IE9 and below)...

Comment: I analyzed your page and you might take a look at the things I marked as red: http://prntscr.com/cvcdot